# Javascript Form derivation verbs

Tags: javascript

I'm new on javascript. I would like to create a Javascript/HTML5 interface where we can write a verbe and get the noun of the agent. For ex. : sing --> singer

But it doesn't work. It seems it can't save the value required to create the agent.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>
    <form name="txtbox">
    V : <input id = "V" type="text">
    </form>

    </body>

    <script>
    var verbe = get.ElementById('V');
    function nom_derive (verbe) {

  var base = verbe.substr(0,verbe.length-2);
  var agent = base+"eur";

  document.writeln(verbe," est l\'action du ", agent,".\n");

}

nom_derive(verbe);
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: `get.ElementById`? 1) Don't try to guess function names: look them up in the documentation 2) Find your browser's console so you see error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed some concepts. The way it was coded, variable verbe contained a reference to the input box, not the value. And function was called "onload", before you typed some thing.

Take a look at this code if you can continue from it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<form name="txtbox">
V : <input id = "V" type="text">
<input id="B" type="button" value="Go" />
</form>

</body>

<script>
var verbe = document.getElementById('V');
function nom_derive (verbe) {

var base = verbe.value.substr(0,verbe.value.length-2);
var agent = base+"eur";

alert(verbe.value + " est l\'action du " + agent + ".");

}

document.getElementById('B').onclick=function() {
nom_derive(verbe);
};
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What is ".value"? Have I always to put a submit button? However it doesn't work. It seems always not considering the submitted verb

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
var verbe = get.ElementById('V');
```

to:

```
var verbe = document.getElementById('V').value;
```